# Не отображаются подсказки из SuggestView на iPhone

Tags: css, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты, tilda

Появилась проблема с отображением подсказок из [SuggestView](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/SuggestView) только на телефонах iPhone. При попытке открыть подсказки из [SuggestView](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/SuggestView) на компьютере или мобильном телефоне на Android, то проблемы нет, проблема ТОЛЬКО НА IPHONE.

Чтоб воссоздать проблему:

1. Перейдите по ссылке https://agon-shashlyk.ru/katalog
2. Добавьте любой товар в корзину [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Перейдите в корзину [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Попробуйте ввести адрес в данном поле на iPhone(в эмуляторе через DevTools все работает верно)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас и на десктопе если открыть никаких подсказок нет. Яндекс для подсказок отделил сервис Геосаджест, ключ которого должен быть подключен. Быть может Тильда его не пробрасывает тем модулем, что использован? К Тильде вопрос. А так и в консоли вообще запросов в саджест не видно — вот и результат не выводится.

Comment: Добрый вечер, @YaCor' . Да, я знаю про разделение этих двух сервисов, я использую два ключа, свой для каждого сервиса. У меня на компьютере отображаются подсказки корректно, проверьте еще раз, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не скажу наверняка, но из доступных нескольких устройств вижу, что ситуация актуальна только с 15-й версии ios, предыдущие, что планшеты, что смартфоны, открывают подсказки нормально. Но выглядят эти подсказки там по-разному. Смею предположить, что всё же причиной являются CSS-стили, которые как-то завязаны на user-agent или не знаю что ещё. Тильда — та ещё заноза в одном месте, когда сложный сторонний js-код нужно разместить.

Comment: @YaCor' Пробовал через DevTools safari открыть, вижу что, подсказки, то есть, но они под popup(под корзиной) находятся. Точнее за корзиной

Это я увидел, когда подключил iPhone7 через шнур к MacBook

Comment: Значит вопрос в z-index? По какой-то причине popup получает более верхнеуровневый индекс? У меня возможности проверить через DevTools нет, если справитесь, чирканите сюда, в чём всё же дело было — может ещё кому поможет.

Comment: Добрый вечер @Yacor' , в чем причина так не разобрался, пробовал играться с разными zIndex, не помогло, но помогло свойство [options.container](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/SuggestView#param-options.container), пришлось по выбирать разные элементы, чтоб заработало.

Спасибо что уделил внимание вопросу!)